# 2D Array Printing with punctuation

Tags: java, arrays, printing, 2d

So I'm a beginning coder and I'm working on a program for class that prints a basic 2D array with data similar to a school grade program.

```
public class Skyward {
     public void Student(){
      String [][] studentArray=new String[3][4];

      String lastName1="Brown";
      String lastName2="Johnson";
      String lastName3="Michaelson";
     //variables for LastName

      String name1="Bob";
      String name2="Jenny";
      String name3="Michael";
   //variables for FirstName

      String grade1="11";
      String grade2="10";
      String grade3="12";
    //variables for Grade

      String t1grade1="A";
      String t1grade2="C";
      String t1grade3="F";
     //variables for T1Grade

     studentArray[0][0]=lastName1;
     studentArray[0][1]=name1;
     studentArray[0][2]=grade1;
     studentArray[0][3]=t1grade1;

    studentArray[1][0]=lastName2;
    studentArray[1][1]=name2;
    studentArray[1][2]=grade2;
    studentArray[1][3]=t1grade2;

    studentArray[2][0]=lastName3;
    studentArray[2][1]=name3;
    studentArray[2][2]=grade3;
    studentArray[2][3]=t1grade3;

 for ( int row=0; row < studentArray.length; row++ ) {
      for ( int col=0; col < studentArray[row].length; col++ ){
          System.out.print(studentArray[row][col]);
            System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print(" -Grade- ");
            System.out.print(" T1Grade- ");
    }//end inner loop
      System.out.println("");
   }//end outer loop
}//end method
  }//end class
```

I need it to print as "LastName, FirstName-Grade-x-T1Grade-y", but instead it comes out like this

```
        Brown,  -Grade-  T1Grade- Bob,  -Grade-  T1Grade- 11,  -Grade-  T1Grade- A,  -Grade-  T1Grade-
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, mostly on the punctuation and for loops. I tried looking at other 2D array printing issues on this website but since I'm still fairly new at coding, most of the other questions or their answers go over my head. Any tips you have would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is not needed. It iterates for the number of columns in `studentArray`, so it's calling all of the `System.out.prints` each iteration. You could instead use the following:

```
for ( int row=0; row < studentArray.length; row++ ) {
      System.out.print(studentArray[row][0])
      System.out.print(", " + studentArray[row][1]);
      System.out.print(" -Grade- " + studentArray[row][2]);
      System.out.print(" T1Grade- " + studentArray[row][3]);
      System.out.println("");
}//end loop
```